# "IOError [Errno 13] Permisson denied" when copy a file on Windows

Tags: python, windows

I wrote a program that will copy a file called a.exe to `C:/Windows/`, then I pack it to exe with PyInstaller, and rename the exe file to a.exe. When I run the exe file, it output `IOError [Errno 13] Permisson denied: 'C:/Windows/a.exe'`, but the file `a.exe` **was copied to the directory** `C:/Windows`. Then I ran it as the Administrator, it happened again...
At first, I copy the file with `shututil.copy`, then I wrote a function myself(open a.exe, create a.exe under C:/Windows, read a.exe 's content and write to C:/Windows/a.exe, close all), but it doesn't help...Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if a.exe has read-only attribute. shutil.copy raises "Permission denied" error when it is called to overwrite existing file with read-only attribute set

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you're trying to execute a file that moves itself to a different place ... I guess that cannot work.

Comment: Please consider posting the relevant parts of your source code here, otherwise I'll only be able to guess what you're trying.

Comment: Sorry...I just thought that you could try it out with just a few lines of code ..

Answer (score 0):

Can you copy files that are open in Windows? I have a vague memory that you can't, and the file will be open while you execute it.

Is it really being copied? It doesn't exist there before copying? Did it copy the whole file?

Comment: Yes, it's copied, and even can be executed